# Gitlab CI environment lint syntax incorrect

Tags: gitlab, environment, gitlab-ci, lint

Trying to check my `.gitlab-ci.yml` for errors and discovered this through the CI Lint in CI/CD section. The following section throws syntax incorrect even though it's according to https://my.gitlab-instance/help/ci/environments

```
environment:
  name: staging
  url: https://staging.example.com
```

Produces this lint error:

```
Status: syntax is incorrect
Error: jobs:environment config contains unknown keys: name, url
```

Even trying to hack away with adding dashes like this

```
environment:
  - name: staging
  - url: https://staging.example.com
```

Which gives this instead

```
Status: syntax is incorrect
Error: jobs:environment config should be a hash
```

Any ideas how to do this correct?

Comment: Can you post your full `.gitlab-ci.yml`? I suspect it could be an issue with how you're using the `environment` keyword, and instead of using it within a job, you have it as a job instead.

Comment: We updated to the latest version of Gitlab and the lint seemed to work after that. Strange fix but seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team updated Gitlab instance to latest version and the lint error have since disappeared. No idea if this was the actual fix to the lint error but seemed to be working since then.